How to get historical account info?
I know there's a Solana JSON RPC getAccountInfo, that allows me to get the current state of an account (e.g., its lamport balance, owner, data size, data, etc...). I'm wondering if I can get the state of an account at a given block? For example, I want to get the lamport balance of an account 24 hours ago.
In Ethereum, this is possible, because multiple Ethereum JSON RPCs support the block parameter. In this way, I can pass in a block number to get the blockchain state of a past time. Is this possible in Solana?

Update: Here's my use case. I want to get all owners of an NFT collection (i.e., Metaplex collection) at a past time.

Looking at the doc (https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getaccountinfo) i don't think you can do it with solana.
However, if you want to get the account balance history, you can fetch signatures involving this account, then transactions, and in transactions you have the pre/post lamports balances (and tokens also).

Thanks for answering! I've updated my question. I don't want to get the account balances. I want to get all owners of an NFT collection at a past time.

i think then the only way is to fetch all transactions for nfts mint addresses, and check for transfer instructions (take care of marketplace listings, stakings...)...
